# Nginx not calling static files on site

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates, django-deployment

Django works fine but static files are not called

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.bakuklinik.shop bakuklinik.shop;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    autoindex    on;
    alias /root/myprojectdir/;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on DigitalOcean

You can view the site here: http://bakuklinik.shop/

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem didn't work

Comment: make sure you restart nginx and gunicorn service after you make the changes

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. And please don't forget to restart your server.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/'),)
```